# Dynamically added JavaScript script continues to execute when removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm creating a SPA and I am using AJAX to load HTML pages in to the index page of my site. The issue is that when one of my pages is included it seems to hang around and execute the JavaScript code within it even though it is then removed from the DOM.

**index.html (body)**

```
<div id="ui_container"></div>
```

**tutorial.html**

```
<div id="ui_container">
    <div id="ui_top_left_section" style="display: none">
        <div id="ui_heart_icon_1" class="fa fa-heart"></div>
        <div id="ui_heart_icon_2" class="fa fa-heart"></div>
        <div id="ui_heart_icon_3" class="fa fa-heart"></div>
    </div>

    <div align="center" id="ui_operator_choice_section" style="display: none">
        <div id="plus" class="ui_operator_choice">+</div>
        <div id="minus" class="ui_operator_choice">−</div>
        <div id="multiply" class="ui_operator_choice">×</div>
        <div id="divide" class="ui_operator_choice">÷</div>
        <div id="equal" class="ui_operator_choice">=</div>
        <div id="join" class="ui_operator_choice fa fa-long-arrow-left"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="ui_top_right_section" style="display: none">
        <div id="ui_restart" class="fa fa-refresh"></div>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <div class="ui_go_back_to_home clickable fa fa-bars"></div>
    </div>

    <div align="center" class="ui_equation_container" style="display: none">
        <div class="ui_number_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_empty_operator_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_number_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_empty_operator_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_number_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_empty_operator_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_number_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_empty_operator_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_number_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_empty_operator_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_number_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_empty_operator_box"></div>
        <div class="ui_number_box"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="assets/js/app/game_new.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app/tutorial.js"></script>
```

The two scripts that are loaded in dynamically from **tutorial.html** seem to still execute even when content from `#ui_container` is emptied and replaced with new content. Below is how I load the HTML pages:

```
function to (page_name, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: page_name + '.html',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        async: true,

        beforeSend: function () {

        },

        success: function (page) {
            $('#ui_container').html(page);

            return is_function(callback) ? callback(page) : true;
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, text_status, error_thrown) {
            console.log(text_status);
        }
    });
}
```

### Example

[This](https://i.gyazo.com/3381b5c94224260e190bfceab3b588be.mp4) GIF should explain what I mean:

When I click the tutorial button, it loads the content of the above posted file and places it `#ui_container` and everything works correctly.

The issue is that when I then go back to the main menu it still again displays that pop-up for some reason even though the DOM content has been removed.

I then inspected the network tab and found that **tutorial.html** (and the scripts within it) were being called again even when going back to the menu. Image below outlines what has been mentioned:

[image]

Why is this happening?

**Update #1**

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function () {  
    if (self.hasClass('back_to_home') || self.hasClass('ui_go_back_to_home'))
        return to('home');

}
```

**Update #2**

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui_operator_choice', function () {

});

$(document).on('click', '#ui_restart', function () {

});
```

Comment: Do those scripts create event handlers, and if so, are they ever destroyed?

Comment: @FrankModica they create two click handlers, and no, how would that be done?

Comment: Apparently one or both of the two scripts in the injected code set up a reference to the DOM objects (by declaring them as globals for example), so when you remove them from the DOM you're not deleting them really, you're just cutting them out from the DOM (they still exist because a reference to them still exist, so the garbage collector can't destroy them).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir how would I remove the references too?

Comment: Can you post the codes for `game_new.js` and `tutorial.js`?

Comment: @FrankModica I've included the click listeners.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir `game_new.js` is a rather large file so it might be difficult, just to let you know it has no event listeners inside it.

Comment: You can use `$.off` to remove event handlers. But make sure you remove them before you remove the `DOM`. Also consider attaching events to elements rather than DOM, makes them easier to remove or not execute in absence of elements. Since I don't know the contents of the files, I would suggest you to use `singleton` or single variable pattern in those file so that you can set that variable to `null` to remove them as well as their effect from window or DOM.

Comment: Your click handlers are on `document`, so they will persist. You should destroy them at the appropriate time, using `off` (the opposite of `on` as you are using here)

Comment: @FrankModica I'm unsure about how to go about this, considering it is AJAX content and the event is attached to `document` so if I do `                $(document).off('click');` everything stops working and if I do `$('.ui_operator_choice').off('click'); $('#ui_restart').off('click');` it still shows the popup.

Comment: Why would this be otherwise ? JS engines doesn't care where the code comes from, once compiled, it stays in the memory no matter if the js markup is in the doc or not, I mean, what would you expect for code you execute from the console ? Or even, do you expect that `var x = Math.random()` to really write in the `<script>` `"var x = 0.9249251082250056"` ? If you want to append HTML which contains `<script>` elements, without executing these scripts, then please clarify your question.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad the pop-up shows as a result of the file being loaded, not the actual events.

Comment: @Kaiido my naivety had me thinking that due to the code no longer being in the DOM, it would no longer execute as the (apparent) reference to it had gone. How I can remove it so it doesn't execute that piece of code to show the pop-up, I've tried `off` but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Well it's really unclear. Do you want to clean-up what these scripts did, or do you want to never execute it ? The former wold imply a rewrite of all the scripts being loaded, the latter is quite simple.

Comment: @Kaiido when I leave the tutorial page (as shown in the GIF) I do not wish it to re-execute the JavaScript files from the tutorial page unless the page is explicitly accessed as opposed to it currently implicitly loading them when it is not accessed.

Comment: Then use iframes, and load it only when you click on the corresponding link.

Comment: When are you executing this code ? `$('.ui_operator_choice').off('click'); $('#ui_restart').off('click');` before or after removing elements from DOM? Also can you try this code? `$(document).off('click', '.ui_operator_choice', function () {});

$(document).off('click', '#ui_restart', function () {});` Note that there is an empty function in the handler.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad the code is being executed before the `to()` function places the new content in to the DOM.

Comment: @Kaiido is there no other solution while maintaining the current design?

Comment: @Script47, can you please try the other solutions that I gave?

Comment: if it's always the same script ... you could also load the script only if it has been loaded : `if(!document.querySelector('script[href="tutorial.js"]')){appendTutorialScript())}` but that seems a really bad design to me. And before appending your html, you'd need to [parse it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), and exclude the scripts.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad tried, still no luck, I need to somehow remove the file(s) from memory to prevent it from executing the code once the user leaves the page.

Comment: @Script47, I think safe and easy option is to use variable or singleton pattern in those js files so that you can directly set them to null to remove them from memory or in a bad sense, as a last chance have a look at these http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ or http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/