# Forcing garbage collection in JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, html, dom, garbage-collection

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479890/dynamically-added-javascript-script-continues-to-execute-when-removed-from-the-d) and what I can gather from the responses is that I need to force the garbage collector to remove code which has been removed from the DOM but where references still exist in memory. I've looked around and I can't seem to find a proper solution, in 2017, is there a viable way to collect the garbage?

**Scenario**

```
function class_blah() {
    this.var_blah = 'blah';

    this.func_blah = function () {};
}

var blah = new class_blah();

/** Stuff happens here... **/
```

Then say I remove that dynamically loaded script and load some more content in to the DOM, how I can get garbage collector to now remove that?

***The linked question should give you a better idea in regards to the issue I'm facing.***

Comment: One last thing before leaving: Here is an [**article**](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/javascript-game-foundations-state-management/) about **game state management**, There is tons of similar articles online, you may find them very very very helpful to organise the logic of your game.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir will take look at it, almost 6 AM here so I'm going to call it a night (day?), thanks once again.

Comment: Almost 5am here, time-neighbor. I'll call it a night too. Farewell!